# Assign inside or out of loop?

Tags: c#

I would like to assign a value if P true then run a while loop with P.

This is the obvious solution:

```
int thevalue = 0;

// Calculate P

if(P)
{
     theValue = 2;
}
while(P)
{
    // Do something without modifying theValue and calculate P
}
```

But this looks nicer to me:

```
int theValue = 0;

// Calculate P

while(P)
{
    theValue = 2;
    // Do something without modifying theValue and calculate P
}
```

Will it assign every time the loop runs? Compiler could optimize this.

Is it a good practice?

EDIT:

The value is used after the loop.

The value should not change if P false when it examined.

More clear question:
If the while loop runs like a "billion times" is the assign in the loop ineffective and an unnecessary CPU cycle?

Comment: Yes, it will assign the same value every loop iteration.

Comment: And the compiler could only optimize it away if it could prove that nothing else would be setting it to a different value. As we don't know whether this is a field or a local variable, or what any of the rest of the code looks like, it's hard for us to tell based solely on the code you've provided.

Comment: It will assign the same value on each iteration of while loop. If you are not worrying about the value of `theValue` inside the whole loop, the code is ok.

Comment: I modified the "Will it.. " part to be more clear.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Local variable and as the comment says not modified in the loop. No paralell programming, etc. Nothing will modify it.

Comment: Why do you even declare the value outside the loop? Do you need it afterwards?

Comment: @headsvk Yes, I do.

Comment: If you are setting value of `P` to true in the same code block then you can set the value of `theValue` at the same place. You don't need to check P for true after that

Comment: I'd probably initialize it at the point of declaration: `int theValue = P ? 2 : 0;`

Comment: It look like I generalized too much. Question edited. I dont know P yet. And P can depend on theValue. So it should not do when theValue initialized.

Comment: @PetSerAl: The only benefit I see of that over the first approach shown in the question is to evaluate `P` one less time... whereas it doesn't look as readable to me. Given what we now know, I'd probably stick with the first code.

Comment: this short fragment, I assume is from bigger code, probably in bigger version has different semantic

Answer (score 2):

Functionally it is equivalent, but I'll address the 'good practice'...

P is clearly not invariant since otherwise your while loop would never terminate!  If it's not invariant then the starting/initial condition you use in your 'if' statement must be different from the evaluation for each iteration of the loop.

I think what you are really *trying* to say with the 'if' statement is   "set the value if the while loop will be evaluated at least once".   As  a matter of style I would write the code to make this intent clearer.   If you can use a collection then I would suggest a pattern such as....

```
var theValue = collection.Any() ? 2 : someSensibleDefault;
foreach (var thing in collection)
{
}
```

If it truly is a test condition...

```
var theValue = (initialP)  ? 2 : someSensibleDefault;
while (P)
{
}
```

As a final comment, I really wouldn't consider worrying about optimisation here - the goal should be to express what you trying to do.

Comment: I threw the ternary operator because I should not change theValue if P false. And this is ugly: `var theValue = P ? 2 : theValue;`

Comment: As other people have said, it's a bit hard to suggest a sensible pattern without more context.  Is 'theValue' used _after_ the while loop?  Some of your answers imply it simply used as a parameter in the calculation of P.  In which case why not create a method that calculates P and takes the 'theValue' as a parameter?  We'll have to agree to disagree on the ugliness of the ternary operator - to me it is a far better expression of intent :)